# blackberry application UI get displaced when installed in phone(bb curve 9220)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

i developed a blackberry application in eclipse...It looks good in simulator...I mean perfect. but i installed it in blackberry phone(blackberry 9220 curve)...The widgets are displaced and some are very big and certain wi

Comment: Is it the same simulator that you are using (Simulator == 9220 curve)?

Comment: no i used 9900 simulator

Comment: Then it is bound to happen.  Different screens have different window sizes and resolution.  I used the simulator that comes with eclipse plugin (don't remember the name) and I had to resize my application on blackberry bold by trial and error.  However there may be other methods which I don't know.

Comment: Thanku sathish...Is there any trick in blackberry so that my application runs in different screens and resolutions

Comment: I tried to use screenwidth and used somthing like leftMargin = 0.1*screenwidth like that.

Comment: Can u give a sample code explaining that

Comment: my system crashed 2 days back.  I am in process of getting my system up and running.  I will try to provide after 2-3 days.